# How do I calculate the maximum value of a pixel across multiple input images in Google Earth Engine to find the maximum NDVI?

Tags: ndvi, max

I'm doing some NDVi analysis using S2 and because my AOI has quite varied seasons with regards to cropping cycles I need to extract out the max NDVI for each pixel across a number of input images.
The code I've got so far is:

```js
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  //Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
    var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
    var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  //Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
    var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2");

//Set AOI Min Lon, Min Lat, Max Lon, Max Lat
var aoi = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-alcisgeo/assets/UKR_Admin0');

var filteredMar = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 80))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-03-01', '2020-03-31'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(aoi));
var filteredApr = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 80))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-04-01', '2020-04-30'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(aoi)); 
var filteredMay = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 80))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-05-01', '2020-05-31'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(aoi));
var filteredJun = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 80))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-06-01', '2020-06-30'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(aoi));
var filteredJul = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 80))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-07-01', '2020-07-31'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(aoi));
var filteredAug = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 80))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-08-01', '2020-08-31'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(aoi));
var filteredSep = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 80))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-09-01', '2020-09-30'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(aoi));
var filteredOct = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 80))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-10-01', '2020-10-31'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(aoi));

  
var imageMar = filteredMar.median(); 
var imageApr = filteredApr.median();
var imageMay = filteredMay.median();
var imageJun = filteredJun.median();
var imageJul = filteredJul.median();
var imageAug = filteredAug.median();
var imageSep = filteredSep.median();
var imageOct = filteredOct.median();

// Calculate  Normalized Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI)
// 'NIR' (B8) and 'RED' (B4)
var ndviMar = imageMar.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename(['ndviMar']);
var ndviApr = imageApr.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename(['ndviApr']);
var ndviMay = imageMay.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename(['ndviMay']);
var ndviJun = imageJun.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename(['ndviJun']);
var ndviJul = imageJul.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename(['ndviJul']);
var ndviAug = imageAug.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename(['ndviAug']);
var ndviSep = imageSep.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename(['ndviSep']);
var ndviOct = imageOct.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename(['ndviOct']);

//Display properties
var ndviVis = {min:0.23, max:1, palette: ['yellow', 'green', 'blue']};

Map.centerObject(aoi, 7);

//Add images to map
Map.addLayer(ndviMar.clip(aoi), ndviVis, 'March');
Map.addLayer(ndviApr.clip(aoi), ndviVis, 'April');
Map.addLayer(ndviMay.clip(aoi), ndviVis, 'May');
Map.addLayer(ndviJun.clip(aoi), ndviVis, 'June');
Map.addLayer(ndviJul.clip(aoi), ndviVis, 'July');
Map.addLayer(ndviAug.clip(aoi), ndviVis, 'August');
Map.addLayer(ndviSep.clip(aoi), ndviVis, 'September');
Map.addLayer(ndviOct.clip(aoi), ndviVis, 'October');
```

So for instance I want the max pixel values as an output with Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul as my inputs?

Comment: Are you measuring the effect the war has on Ukrainian crops/NDVI?